# Springboot schema init doesn't work while import by another maven module

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I have a maven project that include some modules(such as web, backend, base and so on) that build on Spring boot.

Now I want to do database initialization by spring.sql.* configs.

When I put **_schema.sql files in web module, it works, but when I put the schema files in base module then I run web module, it fails.

Note: my application.properties is out of the project and pass by command line parameters when I run the project.

How to make schema.sql work in base module, so I can reuse them when I run backend module.

Answer (score 0):

In the base module add build config in pom.xml, codes are below

```
<resources> 
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.ddl</include>
            <include>**/*.sql</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

then it works.